# Is it okay to leave job without notice if the contract ends?

Tags: resignation, project-management, stress, leave

I am working on a project and my contract only lasts for a few more weeks and so it is unlikely to be finished by that point.

Working from home has been really tough for me and I’m not enjoying it. I developed a number of health issues because of the stress I have felt for the past few months.

I am young and so don’t want to make my employer angry at me and burn bridges, but as my contract ends soon, I think it might be best for me to leave.

Does this look bad on me not finishing a project and would I have to give notice of leaving even though the current contract ends?

Comment: The contract has an end date - the company knows that date, so needs no notice. If they fail to try and extend it that is on them.

Comment: Do you estimate how much time your tasks take? When you update your estimations the next time, you can tell your boss/manager that your exit date is close.

Comment: What does the contract say?

Comment: Where are you located? Depending on the place you'll have to communicate that you don't intend to renew it

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza Spain

Comment: Is there a real chance you will be able to work from the office elsewhere? I know working from home is not for everyone, but the worldwide pandemic is the reason here, not some random policy of the company.

Answer (score 12):

Notice is a concept which applies only to indefinite contracts (or potentially if you want to end a fixed term contract before its defined expiration date). Everybody *should* be aware of the end date and, barring any extension to the contract, knows you're going to leave then.

That said, sometimes things get forgotten. You wouldn't do yourself any harm to say to remind the people that you're working with that your contract is ending a couple of weeks beforehand, and ask if there are any handover tasks they want you to work on. Does you no harm whatsoever and means you can exit gracefully - worst case scenario here is that they offer you an extension, which you can politely decline.

Answer (score 5):

If they don't want to secure your services with a new contract, that's on them. Personally, I would remind them that the contract is ending, but that's just me.

If they do offer you a new contract, talk about ending the Work From Home policy, negotiating some vacation time, and increasing your rates. Since you don't really want the job, it will be easy for you to play hardball.

But in the meantime, look for another job, you will feel much more confident leaving this one employer when you have offers from others. And if you do accept another job, negotiate a later start date to give you time to recover.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think I should make them aware now that I plan to leave? Maybe they suggest I leave now instead.

Comment: @Amarillo45, If they tell you to leave now instead, is that what you want? If you don't want that, wouldn't they be violating the contract? How much notice does the contract require (assuming it's terminated before it expires)? Read your contract. This is very important. Definitely, be careful before revealing your hand.

Comment: Amarillo if you are willing to continue work with changes, then it would be tactically better to tell them that you want changes, not that you want to leave. If you decided to leave, you can tell them. Be careful not to tell them too early, so they can't just lay you off.

Comment: @gnasher729 would you be able to elaborate a bit on that please?

Comment: @Amarillo45, I'm not gnasher, but this part: "Be careful not to tell them too early, so they can't just lay you off." will completely depend on the exact wording of your contract and the jurisdiction you're in. If the contract stipulates a notice period of x days if they terminate you before the contract is expired, then that means that you're protected for those x notice days even if you do tell them.

Answer (score 4):

Absent further information, it sounds like your contract is for "time", rather than "work product", i.e. you are available for a fixed amount of time.

In which case, yes it's fine to leave when the contract is finished and without giving notice. You're right to be concerned about them being angry the project is unfinished, but the worst that's likely to happen in that respect is you won't get a good reference.

Just be careful about having something else to go to afterwards. Don't know what industry you're in, but in IT everything comes to halt mid/late December for a month.

Re stress, maybe you should consider some time off. Perhaps if you can stand to continue working, you could negotiate a new contract to start two weeks after your current one ends. Prioritize your health if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have an obligation to fulfill the terms of your contract. You need to do whatever it says you need to do, and have no obligation to do anything it doesn't. So what does it say you need to do at the end at the end of your term?

That said, regardless of the contractual terms, the courteous thing to do would be to remind your project manager that your contract is ending soon and let them know you do not intend to renew or extend it. They probably already have a lot of balls in the air, so your departure may not be at the top of their mind. The more time you give them prepare for that, the better it will look for you. No one will fault you for taking your career where you want to go, but they may be irked if you just stop showing up one day without saying anything.

Comment: Hi. It says I must prepare a publication but it talks about a project I completed in the last contract.

Comment: If the contract ends before the publication is prepared, then someone else needs to finish preparing it.

Comment: @gnasher729 would I not get in trouble for not finishing it? It says on my contract that’s it’s my job to prepare it. Would they give me bad reference?

Comment: @Amarillo45, that's something you really need to ask your manager. No one here knows the terms of your contract or how far your employer will go to enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed term contract, that requires neither finishing a project (and is frequently used when there is an **expectation** that the project will be unfinished when the term expires), nor “notice” in the sense that a full or part-time employee would use.

What would be professional is to discuss how your work should be handed over or wound down.  Whether you are digging a ditch, writing a computer program or flying a plane, you don’t want to let the clock tick over and then walk away — it’s going to be wasteful at best and disastrous at worse (imagine stepping out of a 747 at cruising altitude because your contract expired during the middle of your flight).

You should determine a good time to have that discussion and then have it.  You should be prepared for the **possibility** that they will want to extend your contract, but realize that you are under no obligation to accept or explain a refusal and they are under no obligation to make such an offer or to explain why they don’t.

Comment: If the OP's contract is ending in a few weeks, and the company is not discussing it already with the OP, then they are also happy with the OP not knowing about their employment status in a few weeks.

Comment: @BarryDeCicco: without further discussion the OPs status in a few weeks is clear — no longer working with this company. What isn’t clear is what the company wants the  OP to be doing between now and then